# Render partial from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement an action which will be invoked when user submits a new comment via ajax. When the comment is saved single comment partial must return. But it seems that render doesn't work as expected from ApplicationController. It displays an error that the view is not found, but it is in place (100%). When I'm adding `:partial` parameter it works, but doesn't pass any variables (and I need them!). Here's the controller code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  def comment
    comment = Comment.new({
      story_id: params[:story_id],
      content: params[:content]
    })
    if comment.save
      render 'shared/comments/comment', comment: comment
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm wondering why aren't you using a CommentsController?

Comment: Since this action will be used by several other controllers, it make sense for me to define it in global controller. And I think it's overkill to use separate controller for one action.

Comment: I have to disagree with you, since this action handles the resource Comment it should be placed in the CommentsController, even if you have a comment form in a non CommentsController view. Also, there is no problem to create a controller for just one action.

Comment: I have to agree with @nicolasiensen. Your action looks like a good candidate for a `create` action inside a `CommentsController`, in keeping with REST practices.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```
render :partial => 'shared/comments/comment', :locals => { :comment => comment }
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, this works, but I've read in documentation that in new versions of Rails, you can just pass your variables without locals array and it works for me in other places, but not here. Why?

Comment: @DimaKnivets, according to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), you should use `object: comment` in that case, not `comment: comment`.

Comment: Yes, in this case since the variable has the same name as the partial, you can use `object: comment`. But I don't see any mention of this being a preferred option in the docs.